# how to convert code of an activity to fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I am converting my activity unto a fragment, then I received an error which I think I just need to add some code, what should I add

```
 private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(NotifMainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
```

errors are from the "NotifMainActivity.this" it says "in progress dialog cannot be applied" I have included an image for you to see the error in actual.[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb9ii.png)

Update. So I have change the "NotifMainActivity.this" with getActivity as suggested by sir Kashif Anwar but doing so made the function of the fragment to not work maybe you can provide me an alternative solution.

Here is the whole code of the fragment(this fragment is the activity of a recyclerview)

```
package com.capstone.jmilibraryapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NotifMainActivity extends Fragment {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
private AdapterNotif mAdapter;

         /*@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifmainactivity);
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncLogin().execute();
}*/
View myView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_notifmainactivity, container, false);
    return myView;
}

private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101/notif.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataNotif> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                DataNotif fishData = new DataNotif();

                fishData.NotifTitle= json_data.getString("notif_Title");
                fishData.NotifMessage= json_data.getString("notif_Message");
//                    fishData.sizeName= json_data.getString("size_name");
                fishData.Date= json_data.getString("notif_date");
                data.add(fishData);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)myView.findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
            mAdapter = new AdapterNotif(getActivity(), data);
            mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There maybe some error try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hey check my answer, accept my answer and upvote it please.

Comment: @KashifAnwar yes it run the application but the function stops working. I'll update my post with the whole code please help me out sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use getActivity() instead of class name,

like this

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog( getActivity() );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: made some corrections and solved it. Your answer is correct thanks.